# Resize Kendo Chart

Tags: javascript, kendo-chart

I am trying to resize a Kendo Chart.  I have multiple charts on the screen and when I drag one to a specific area of the browser I want it to resize.  I initially set my chartArea to 400 x 400 in my javascript and then use the following code to resize.

```
            $(id).kendoChart({
                chartArea: {
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200
                }
            });
            $(id).data("kendoChart").redraw();
```

Before:
[image: Before Resizing]

After:
[image: After Resizing]

Why does my chart go completely blank and not have any data on it?

Update:
Interesting thing I have noticed is that if the chart redraws a second time it shows up correctly (i.e. when I drag a second chart over to the area, the first chart redraws and is correct but the second is now not showing correctly).

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [the API docs](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-resize), the correct way to resize a chart is as follows:

```
var c = $("#chart");
c.kendoChart({
  //options
});

//Then later
c.css("width", "800px")
  .data("kendoChart").resize();
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to move my size to css and things have worked well.